# Unit Testing (PHPUnit): how to login?

Tags: zend-framework, logging, phpunit

I'm writing tests for my current project, made with Zend Framework.
Everything's fine, but I have a problem testing the logged users actions/controllers: I need to be logged in to be able to perform the action/controller.

How can I be logged in PHPUnit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you are saying you want to test actions/controllers, I suppose you are not writting unit-tests, but functional/integration tests -- ie, working with `Zend_Test` and testing via the MVC.

Here is a test-function I used in a project, where I'm testing if logging in is OK :

```
public function testLoggingInShouldBeOk()
{
    $this->dispatch('/login/login');
    $csrf = $this->_getLoginFormCSRF();
    $this->resetResponse();
    $this->request->setPost(array(
        'login' => 'LOGIN',
        'password' => 'PASSWORD',
        'csrfLogin' => $csrf,
        'ok' => 'Login',
    ));
    $this->request->setMethod('POST');
    $this->dispatch('/login/login');
    $this->assertRedirectTo('/');
    $this->assertTrue(Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity());
}
```

Simply : I'm loading the login form, extracting the CSRF token, populating the form, and posting it.

Then, I can test if I'm connected.

With that, you can probably extract the logging-in part, to call it before each one of your tests that require a valid user to be logged-in.

Comment: wow, thanks a lot for this super fast and really good-looking answer.
I go trying this right (and looking in google about CSRF ;-) ) now and keep you posted about my results

Comment: well, I've read about CSRF in the wikipedia, I understand the general idea, please correct me if i'm wrong: this CSRF token is a hidden input with a string identifying the user.
I'm not using this kind of protection (I probably should, though), so I've used your code without the 2 lines about CSRF, and it's working great!
Thanks a lot Pascal, see you around

Comment: If you committing your tests to a VCS like git or svn then you need to be careful about storing the username and password.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way. On my `User` entity I have a `login()` method that puts the user's id into the session and a static variable. What I just do in the test `setUp()` is call `$user->login()` and it works. In testing environment sessions are not used (setting `Zend_Session::$isUnitTested = true` has this effect) and tests rely on the static variable. Just remember to clear the static variable (`logout()` the user) on `tearDown()`.

Comment: hi Emil,
thanks for your answer.
It is very similar, right. Would you mind post some code of it? (I mean the part of putting the user's id in ZendFramework/PHPUnit session.
Actually I am a bit confused, I thaught that wasn't possible because PHPUnit doesn't work like a browser, so your thinking about this could be very interesting for me.

Comment: Sorry david, I lied to you. :) I took a look at the code and edited the response.

Comment: okay, I'm glad that I wasn't totally wrong about session and unit environment.
I'll stay with Pascal's solution for now, but it's good to know there are other options out there.
Cheers Emil.

Answer (score 1):

I think this article could help you:
http://perevodik.net/en/posts/7/
It describes how to create a fake identity you can use to set the environment to a state equivalent to a user being logged in.

Answer (score 0):

In much the same way Pascal is using this function:

```
$this->_getLoginFormCSRF();
```

I have created a generic function that returns the value by loading the form using the form element manager:

> public function _getCSRFHashValueFromForm($formAlias, $csrfName) {
>       $form = $this->servicemanager->get('FormElementManager')->get($formAlias);
>       return $form->get($csrfName)->getValue(); }

This of course assumes that the CSRF is bound to the form and not within any fieldset etc.